# Why curl/libcurl doesn't support sftp?

Tags: sftp, curl

I just discovered this bitter truth: my curl doesn't support sftp.

```
~ curl --version
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.43.0 GnuTLS/3.3.15 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

What'd be the reason to castrate such a useful tool?
Am I supposed to recompile the package on my own or can I consider this as a "bug"/"enhancement" to be filed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be another "dust under the carpet" situation like @dadexix86 hinted.

There's a [question with a trivial answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195545/how-to-enable-sftp-support-in-curl) : **recompile it!**

There's a [bug filed to Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587735) (Ubuntu's upstream) with a fix released 4+ years ago.

There's still no solution for Ubuntu users other than the recompilation one, that get's wiped with the next libcurl upgrade, unless you stick with an old locally recompiled version.

So, no real answer is possible here, only a partial and temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[There is already a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/311029). This was a [problem inherited from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587735), but then it was solved there (in Debian).

And now apparently everything [gets down to a problem with repositories](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/175891) (`curl` is in `main` while the needed libraries are in `universe`, and this goes against [the policies for the `main` section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuMainInclusionRequirements)).

If you want to recompile it I suggest you to follow [this answer on this website](https://askubuntu.com/a/195547/29595).

Comment: Recompilation is not an option in my opinion.  cURL (and libcURL) are not secondary or little known packages. Moreover, manual compilation could/would require user care for subsequent updates/upgrades.